# Painting vertex with 0.1 but it acts as if it has 1.0?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

So, I am painting these vertexes, assigned only to 1 group.

I put the rig in pose mode and start painting, but they move too much, so I lower the strength by a lot and paint again. No effect.

Even if I paint with 0.001 it will deform as if it was 1.0.

Also, if I use 0.5 in one bone and 0.5 in the other one like:

0.5 thigh/ 0.5 leg

If I do this the mesh will shrink when I rotate the leg

This is really frustrating...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a common misconception about how bone deformation weighting is calculated.  The way it actually works is as follows:

If a vertex belongs to one or more vertex groups which are parented to bones, that vertex's bone-deformed location will be equally split between the bones' locations according to the ratio of their respective weights.

The key here is that deformation is calculated based on the *ratio* of weights per vertex, not on the absolute value of each weight.  So if a vertex is only parented to one bone it's deformation location will be *entirely decided* by that one bone, no matter how small a weight it has in that bone's vertex group.

---

To get the vertex's position to be 10% affected by the bone you have to specify what affects the other 90%.  You can do this by adding another bone that does not move to your armature.  Then add a new vertex group for this bone and assign the vertices to this vertex group with a weight of `0.9`.

[image]

In the above example both "legs" are parented to `jointBone` with weight `0.1`, but the right one is also parented to `basisBone` with weight `0.9`.

Comment: I think I might have figured out what is happening:

If I split 50/50 thigh bone and leg bone, the knee will shrink when bending the leg.

Leg has thigh as parent, and thigh has root bone as parent.

Maybe the root bone is the cause of shrinking? However, my root bone doesn't have any weight on the vertexes...

Also, thanks for taking the time to teach a noob :)